# Why so many picky rules about java generics?

Tags: java, generics

In case of arrays we can say `Animal[] animals = new Cat[10];`

But, using generic syntax we can't say `List<Animal> is a` `ArrayList<Cat>`.

`List<Animal>` can refer to any polymorphic base collection of only Animal and 
nothing else for the sake of type safety.

```
public void foo() {
    Cat[] cats = {new Cat(), new Cat()};
    addAnimals(cats);
}

public void addAnimal(Animal[] animals) {
    animals[0] = new Dog(); // No compile time error. But ArrayStoreException
                            // at runtime as the JVM knows the type of animals.
}
```

Had generics been implicitly polymorphic, in the worst case, even if we add some wrong element into a collection and do some stuff similar to the one as in the above code, at most we will get a `ClassCastException` (or some other exception) which also stops program flow like `ArrayStoreException` right?

I have read that in case of generics, because of type erasure, the JVM doesn't know anything about the type of the collection and hence it can't throw an exception like `ArrayStoreException`.

My question is why this much compile time protection in case of `typed` collections? Why so many picky rules with generics? Please provide a correct understanding.

Comment: Is your Animal an Abstract Class or an interface?

Comment: Because, well, type-safety improves robustness, and Java is a type-safe language. You can use JavaScript, Groovy, or whatever other dynamic language if you prefer less type-safe languages. In Java, we prefer not having dogs in a `List<Cat>`.

Comment: Because it is better to catch bugs in compile time rather than let it through to runtime.

Comment: *"at most we will get a ClassCastException (or some other exception) which also stops program flow like ArrayStoreException"* It is not hard to argue that covariance of arrays is the feature Java got wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common misconception that generics was introduced as an extension to the existing Java polymorphism. This is not true. Java generics was introduced to allow for **Compile time type checking**.

```
interface Species {

}

class Animal implements Species {

}

class Cat extends Animal {

}

class Dog extends Animal {

}

class Plant implements Species {

}

class Tree extends Plant {

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    animals.add(new Cat());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    // Not allowed.
    //animals.add(new Tree());

    // The old way.
    List beasts = new ArrayList();
    beasts.add(new Cat());
    beasts.add(new Dog());
    // Allowed - only caught at run time and difficult to find.
    beasts.add(new Tree());

    // The interface way.
    List<Species> living = new ArrayList();
    living.add(new Cat());
    living.add(new Dog());
    // Allowed.
    living.add(new Tree());

}
```

The aim of generics was to make it easy to specify exactly what class the object can handle and have that checked at compile time.

Generics also made the use of interfaces much neater.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is generics are intended to be **type safe**. If `List<Cat>` was a subclass of `List<Animal>` - it would violate it:

```
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
List<Animal> animals = cats;
animals.add(new Dog());
```

The above would compile just fine - but what would happen now when you try to access `cats`? it will have an element which is not a `Cat`, and for instance:

```
for (Cat c : cats) { ...}
```

would fail.

Comment: I think you meant `animals.add(new Dog());`?

Comment: @amit Are you sure List<Animal> animals = cats; will compile?

Comment: @Phoenix It would have compiled if `List<Cat>` was extending `List<Animal>`. Luckily - it is not, so it does not compile.